# Python, how can I define an object O such that func(O) = func(O.val) for any func

Tags: python, oop

How can I define an object such that any function acting on it will act on one of its field? Is this possible?

```
class Mydata(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __str__(self):
        # my changes

a = Mydata(0)
a + 4 # return integer 4
print a # prints my change

b = Mydata([1,2])
b * 2 # return [1,2,1,2]
b[a] # return 1
```

Thanks

Edit: actual problem.

I want to modify the __repr__ method (maybe also other methods) for pandas time series/data frame, but also list/str/... This should apply only under some cases. For example, if I have a pd time series whose values are themselves time series or lists or other non-standard types, then I want that modified printing.

Comment: `class Mydata(object): def __new__(self, val): return val` satisfies your stated requirement. But, for that matter, so does `def Mydata(val): return val`.

Comment: What is the point of this? Why not just use an integer and a list? Even if you implement every magic method, you still won't be able to use your class e.g. as an index for a vanilla list.

Comment: More concretely, what is the "[actual problems that you face](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)"?

Comment: @Robᵩ Thanks. I added the actual problem to the post

Answer (score 4):

In general, you cannot. You'll need to support each desired function in your class. For example, to support addition of a `Mydata` instance and an another value, define `Mydata.__add__` and `Mydata.__radd__`.

```
# For Mydata(4) + 2
def __add__(self, other):
    return self.val + other

# For 2 + Mydata(4)
def __radd__(self, other):
    return self.val + other
```

I've ignored certain details, such as ensuring that this will work for all (or as many as possible) types of `other`.

You'll have to do likewise for multiplication (`__mul__`), etc. See the [documentation on Python's data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) for a list of all the functions you might need to implement to make `Mydata` work with other data types.

Answer (score 1):

You can try inheriting from `int`, as explained [here](http://jfine-python-classes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/subclass-int.html), and from `list`, etc. And if that doesn't suit you for some reason, I would combine it with a [class decorator](http://jfine-python-classes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/decorators.html) (for example, somehow wrapping the class within a subclass of the type of `val`).